„auf dem Schulhof" vs „im Hinterhof"?
Meines Erachtens sind diese zwei Sätze korrekt:

Die Jungen haben sich auf dem Schulhof getroffen.
Die Jungen haben sich im Hinterhof getroffen.

Stimmt das?
Aber wären dann diese Sätze auch richtig?

Die Jungen haben sich im Schulhof getroffen.
Die Jungen haben sich auf dem Hinterhof getroffen.

Wenn nicht, wieso nicht?
Ist es so, dass ein Hinterhof irgendwie wie ein „geschlossener" Raum betrachtet wird?  Oder sind alle diesen Varianten korrekt, nur mit einem feinen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen „auf" und „in"?

Nein, es muss auf dem Schulhof heißen.
Beim Hinterhof ist beides möglich. Das im rührt daher, dass Hinterhöfe normalerweise rundum von Mauern umgeben sind und ein auf dann nicht wirklich passt.

Schulhöfe sind normalerweise umzäunt. Es scheint mir eher ein konzeptueller denn ein realweltlicher Unterschied zu sein.

@JonathanHerrera: Zumindest bei weiterführenden Schulen wäre es mir neu, dass Schulhöfe generell umzäunt sind. Und auch bei Grundschulen ist das nicht immer der Fall, wenn der Schulhof anderweitig baulich von der Umgebung abgetrennt ist.

@O.R.Mapper Ich hab noch nie einen Schulhof gesehen, der nicht - wie ein Hinterhof, und darum geht es hier ja - baulich abgetrennt ist, entweder durch einen Zaun oder eben andere Gebäude.


Oder sind alle diesen Varianten korrekt, nur mit einem feinen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen „auf" und „in"?

Das kommt wohl darauf an, auf welchen Teil des deutschen Sprachgebiets diese Frage abzielt.
Im "Bundesdeutsches Deutsch" sprechenden Teil (damit meine ich, sehr unwissenschaftlich, im Wesentlichen die BRD minus dem Teil, in dem Niederbairisch gesprochen wird) wird wohl "auf dem Schulhof" das einzig richtige sein, wie schon @Janka in seiner Antwort bemerkte, allerdings geht man dort auch "zur Schule", ist "auf der Schule" (wenn man dort als Schüler registriert oder grade dort ist), "auf [der] Arbeit" und manche sind sogar "auf einem Haus".
Der "bairische Varietäten" sprechende Teil (damit ist ungefähr Niederbayern, Österreich minus Vorarlberg und Südtirol gemeint) Bereich verwendet durchaus "im Schulhof", geht "in die Schule" ist "an einer Schule", "in der Arbeit" und befindet sich entweder "in einem Haus" oder draußen.
Wie das im alemannischen Teil (Vorarlberg, Schweiz) gehandhabt wird, kann ich nicht im Detail sagen.

Wenn man zur Schule geht, sollte man morgens zu der Schule gehen, auf die man geht, und tunlichst vor Unterrichtsbeginn in die Schule und in den Klassenraum gehen - und in den Pausen wieder auf den Schulhof.

@planetmaker: Es könnte sein, daß der Grund für das schlechte Abschneiden der Deutschen bei PISA darin liegt, daß sie "zur Schule" gehen, wir hingegen "in die Schule" - Wir gehen auch rein!

Hehe, möglich. Dabei ist doch am wichtigsten, was rauskommt. :)

Wäre „an der Arbeit" auch richtig?

@Cerulean: yes, but that has a different meaning. "In der Arbeit" means "at the place where the work happens", i.e. "im Büro" (at the office). "An der Arbeit" means "being at work" - being busy right now.
